# Navigating unique alerts in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, alert

I am currently automating a website with Selenium, when I encountered the following alert: [image: Picture of dialog box] I have no access to the HTML of the page. I need to enter a number into the first field, and then select the "Expand" button.

When I opened the dialog box, I noticed that the focus was on the textbox, so I attempted:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
actions.sendKeys(Integer.toString(2));
actions.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
actions.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

However, this didn't end up entering the information into the field or selecting "expand", but it also didn't crash the application.

I also tried:

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.sendKeys(Integer.toString(2));
alert.accept();
```

This did crash the application, and returned the error:
Modal dialog did not have a text box - maybe it was an alert.

Is there any way you can think of to interact with the alert?

EDIT: it appears that the new window allows me to use `driver.switchTo().alert()` and `driver.switchTo().window("genericWindowHandle")`. I am not sure if this is normal or if it may help decide what this alert/window actually is.

Comment: Looks like a new window to me

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly a window - notice the title bar. Besides when this shows up, you can easily verify if it is a window or not by looking at the quick start options bar (usually at the bottom of the screen on Mac and Windows). A new window will be recognized but a dialog box will not be.

This looks like a window and what you have is normal and expected.

Comment: While it is a good observation, this still doesn't answer the actual question: How can you interact with the window without using By locators.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow this comment - you mean you want to access the text box and the button without the By locators or you mean that you are unable to access the elements with the By locators after switching into them? In my experience, you should be able to access them as usual (using the By locators) once you've switched into them

Comment: Oh.. I just noticed that you are using IE as your browser - there's a lot of stuff in Selenium that do are not supported or do not work well with IE. Could you let me know if the code works with Firefox but not IE? You will have your culprit then.

Comment: Sadly, the webpage I am working with is only supported by IE 8, it is one of the reasons that I am having so much trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I have got this problem, where the title of page is Webpage dialog same as you. In this window you can not inspect the element. 
Solution to this is go to

```
Internet Explorer--> 
Internet Options --> 
Security tab -->
Custom Level --> 
Disable the option : Allow Websites to open windows without address or status bar
```

Now, You can inspect element by F12 in IE.
now, simply write all the selenium commands,
you can also use JavaScriptExecutor for that, If you dialog box calls JavaScript.